# Remote kernel cache memory bug

Tags: remote-access, kernel-startup, high-performance-clusters

I have a remote kernel (university cluster) that I can use to evaluate my Mathematica files. However, I put the wrong login details a few times, and now once I open the Mathematica, it somehow has stored it in its cache memory that doesn't seem to be removable. So, I can not access and even the concerned guy has no idea bout it.

I tried a few things:

1. Remove all the files of Mathematica.
2. Re-install Mathematica.
3. Removed and Added back the KernelID.

But nothing seems to have worked. I believe it is some kind of a bug?
I have a MacOS with M1 chip processor and Mathematica 13.3

Comment: Talk to Wolfram Support: they are best qualified to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: @MarcoB, Thanks a lot for the idea! I have done that

Comment: Have you tried clearing your computer's cache?  At least on Windows, it will remove all cookies (and perhaps ome other things),

Comment: @bbgodfrey I tried clearing the Mathematica cache from MacOS folder called Mathematica. However, I guess it is also stored in the folder of MacOS somewhere...

Comment: The internet browser on your computer probably also has a cache.  If Mathematica is exchanging information with that browser, then you may need to clear its cache too.